# Firestore fetching data and empty class properties

Tags: swift, class, google-cloud-firestore

i have a firestore request where i put data in my arrays, but when i do object of this class in another ViewContollers i have nil.

Struct

```
struct Game {    
    
    var gameCategories = ["Classic", "Relationship"]
    var classicCategory: [String]? = []
    var relationshipCategory: [String]? = []
    var mineCategory: [String]? = []

}
```

Class where i fetch data

```
class DataBaseFirestore {
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var game = Game(classicCategory: [], relationshipCategory: [], mineCategory: [])
    
    func getData() {
        db.collection("Classic").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    if let name = document.data()["classic"] as? [String],
                       let name2 = document.data()["relationship"] as? [String] {
                        self.game.classicCategory?.append(contentsOf: name)
                        self.game.relationshipCategory?.append(contentsOf: name2)
                        print(name2)
                        print(name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i fetch data in FirstViewContoller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.loadingDataIndicator.startAnimating()
        data.getData()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3.0) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
```

When i use this in another SecondViewContoller i get nil, whats wrong?

```
var data = DataBaseFirestore()
data.game.classicCategory?.count
```

P.S. How can i do loadingIndicator.startAnimating() while i fetching data from firestore? I did it in URLSession and in Alamofire but cant find the way how should i use it here

Comment: `getData()` is not called in your code. And even if it was, the `count` line returns always `nil` because the data is fetched asynchronously. And why are all category arrays in `Game` optional?

Comment: Updated, still nil. All categories are optional cause i dont know about data in firestore, it can be empty